# refresh javascript after jquery request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to refresh a `<div>` using jQuery to call a PHP script that includes javascript.

After refresh the page is loaded but javascript isn't executed.

My problem is that I do not use javascript function but simply code.

I know I have to use `.on()` or `.live()` but don't know how.

The page I'm trying to call:

```php
require 'connexion.php';  

$statement = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();


echo "<div id='refreshdiv'>";
//  generating content
if (isset($statement))
{
        while($data = $statement->fetch())                              
        {       
?>
<script language="javascript">
var str_in;
var str_out = ""; 
var num_in;
var num_out = "";
var e = "Enter Text!";
var num_out = <?php echo json_encode($data['message']); ?>;
str_out = "";
for(i = 0; i < num_out.length; i += 2) {
num_in = parseInt(num_out.substr(i,[2])) + 23;
num_in = unescape('%' + num_in.toString(16));
str_out += num_in;
}
message = unescape(str_out);
</script>
<?php

                if ($data['user'] == 'user1')
                {
                    echo "<p class='man'>".'Le '.$data['date'].'  '.$data['user'].' à dit:'.'<br>'."\n" ;
                    ?><script language="javascript">document.write(message);</script><?php
                    echo "</p>"."\n" ;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<p class='woman'>".'Le '.$data['date'].'  '.$data['user'].' à dit:'.'<br>'."\n" ;
                    ?><script language="javascript">document.write(message);</script><?php
                    echo "</p>"."\n" ;
                }

        }
}

        echo '</div>';
?>
```

the main page:

```
<script>
function autoRefresh_div()
{
$("#refreshdiv").load("refreshpage.php");
}

setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000); 
</script>

<div id='refreshdiv'><div>
```

Comment: don't use javascript or server-side pages. render everything with php.

Comment: Where do you call a script?

Comment: @Andrew i need to use javascript to code & decode text on the browser to improve privacy on my project

Comment: @Shomz ??? i call from a PHP page to another

Comment: You mean that `require` call? If so, that's *not* an ajax request and you don't need delegated JS event listeners since all the code is pre-rendered.

Comment: @Shomz i use a code like that to refresh on main page
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btReload').click(function() { location.reload(true); });
        setInterval('refreshPage()', 5000);
    });

Comment: It's still not AJAX and you should definitely provide all the relevant code if you want people to help you.

Comment: @Shomz here it is & AJAX has been removed
thanks to you

Comment: initially called AJAX because i take the reloadind script from this page https://matthewaprice.com/article/simple-jquery-ajax-auto-refreshing-div/

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there is absolutely no need to use JS on the page you're calling with AJAX. All of that stuff can be rendered by PHP only, and that's the way you should do it.

Even if it wasn't, running JS code from an AJAX response can be quite unsafe and challenging. You would have to separate the JS code (maybe in a JSON variable) and then run eval() on it... Again, very very unsafe, and not recommended.

If you still want to use JS after the AJAX call, define the function on the main page, and pass it just the arguments you get from the AJAX call. Something like this:

```
function autoRefresh_div() {
    $.get("refreshpage.php", function(res){
        var content = res.htmlContent; // say this is the content for the div
        var jsParam = res.jsParam;     // and this is the JS parameter(s)
        $("#refreshdiv").html(content);
        handleAjax(jsParam);
    });
}

function handleAjax(params) {
    /// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: i've add this to main page without success
should i modify anything else ?

thanks for you warnings, maybe i'm not conducting my personnal project in the right way but i think i can't explain it here.

i'm trying with ajax only too but with the same issues.

Comment: That was just an example of approach. If you wish to do it that way, make sure you can access the data from the php page: for example, you could use `json_encode` on the php page, and then `JSON.parse` in the ajax response. There are many tutorials about sending/parsing JSON data via ajax.